# Question on $Rieman([0,1])$ with norm $\|f\|=\int_0^1|f|$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space $R[0,1]$ the space of Riemann integrable function. This is a metric space with norm $$\|f\|=\int_0^1|f|.$$

I know that in a metric space, if a sequence converges, then its limit is unique. For example, $f_n(x)=x^n$ is a sequence of $R[0,1]$, but $u=0$ or $v=\boldsymbol 1_{\{1\}}$ or $w=\boldsymbol 1_{\{0,1\}}$ are three different limit of $f_n$ in $R[0,1]$.

Q1) How is this possible ?

Q2) If we restrict $R[0,1]$ to $\mathcal C^0[0,1]$, then indeed the limit is unique and is $0$. But I'm not sure : is $\mathcal C^0[0,1]$ complete with this norm ? (like, does every Cauchy sequence converges ?). In this case, I have a Cauchy sequence that indeed converges in $\mathcal C^0[0,1]$ and the limit looks unique. Is it the case of all Cauchy sequence ?

Comment: 1) Do you *actually* know that it's a metric space?
2) If you change the value of a continuous function at a single point, have you changed its Riemann integral in any meaningful way?

Comment: You are right.  It is not a metric space.  To actually get a metric space we need this trick: identify two functions if they agree except on a set of content zero.  Your $u$ and $v$ agree except on $\{1\}$, which has content zero.  Your $w$ is wrong.

Comment: @GEdgar: Sure. Isn't it what we call a "semi-metric" space or "pseudo-mertric" space ? Why my $w$ is wrong ? its integral is $0$ as well.

Comment: @user659895 It's not so much that your $w$ is wrong. You start by saying "In a metric space, iif a limit exists it is unique" - that's simply not true in a semi-metric space.

Comment: You are right.  That small type in the subscript made be confuse brackets $\{,\}$ with brackets $[,]$

Answer (score 4):

The 'norm' that you defined in $R[0,1]$ is not really a norm. Note that $\|\mathbf 1_{\{0\}}\|=0$, and only $0$ should have norm $0$.

If you consider the quotient space $R[0,1]/F$ where $$F=\{f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R\mid f^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\text{ is finite}\},$$ you can work around this problem, and then your sequence converges there to an unique limit. Intuitively, this is like identifying functions that only differ in a finite set of points.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the last part: Let $u_n(t)=0$ for $t \leq \frac 1 2$, $u_n(t)=1$ for $t \geq \frac 1 2 +\frac 1 n$and $u_n(t)=n(t-\frac  1 2)$ for $\frac 1 2 \leq t \leq \frac 1 2+\frac 1 n$. The $(u_n)$ is Cauchy in $C^{0}[0,1]$ with the given norm but it does not converge.